# Javascript & CSS/HTML - Background Change on Mouse Over of DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code in my HTML.

```
 <div class="bg"></div>

        <div class="content" id="hover">

            <div class="one" id="hover-over">1</div> <!--Trigger!-->
            <div class="two">2</div>
            <div class="three">3</div>
            <div class="four">4</div>
            <div class="five">5</div>

        </div>
```

The CSS..

```
.bg {
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
   background: red;
}
```

The Javascript..

```
    var box = document.getElementById("bg");
    var bgChanger = document.getElementById("hover-over");
    //var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");

    function changeBackgroundUp() {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
        //body.style.backgroundColor = "#6fcc6f";
    }

    function changeBackgroundDown() {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
        //body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

    bgChanger.onmouseover = changeBackgroundUp; // 
    bgChanger.onmouseleave = changeBackgroundDown; //
```

A Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bqnw4qyb/56/

**The Problem**

I wish to have the background of the project CHANGED to, for example, green - when the user hovers over one of the DIV elements inside "content". So, when the user hovers over "1", the background of the whole page will change to green. My DIV elements have the background of RED, I don't want this colour to change, only the background color, ideally I would want to change the background to an image using a

```
background: url('someImage');
```

type of system..

I have tried many existing solutions, such as using CSS hover:

```
.one:hover ~ .bg {
background: url('someImage')
}
```

At this stage I am stumped, so any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check the error console!**

You have no `box` object as you have no element with id `bg` only class.

Add add the `id` to the div with class `bg` as well.

```
<div class="bg" id="bg"></div>
```

Also with your current positioning, the bg div is not actually visible.

https://jsfiddle.net/bqnw4qyb/67/

Comment: Thanks very much. I just had to change a few attributes in the CSS, however it is now working fully.   Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bqnw4qyb/69/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function green() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
function red() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
.bg {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
     <div class="bg"></div>
            
            <div class="content" id="hover">
            
                <div class="one" onmouseover="green()" onmouseout="red()" id="hover-over">1</div> <!--Trigger!-->
                <div class="two">2</div>
                <div class="three">3</div>
                <div class="four">4</div>
                <div class="five">5</div>
                
            </div>
```

Please see how I implemented this, is this what you would like?

My program is using the **onmouseover** and the **onmouseout** event.

Please leave any concerns in the comments, hope it helped ;)

Comment: This changes the wrong div, the `bg` background should be changed.